# How to configure CsvHelper.Configuration to use escaping by two start and end characters

Tags: c#, csvhelper

In standard Configuration of CsvHelper library use char type to parameter "Quote".
And standard escape character for CSV is quotation marks. Example: 1;"field; text".
But we use brackets. Example: 1;[field; text].
Moreover, in these brackets there is a separator symbol (;).

Is it possible to configure to ignore these "delimiters" inside parentheses when reading?

I would like to avoid manual preprocessing of the data row when reading. You can, of course, manually replace the extra separators with spaces.

Comment: What you have is actually not csv, but there could be a way, have tried github? John and that community has traditionally been active

Comment: While I am looking for a solution myself and on this forum)
The only thing I can do is read the CSV line by line. And replace square brackets with some Unicode character, which is then passed to CsvConfiguration as a Quote parameter.
Or manually find all pairs of parentheses and replace the delimiters with spaces between them.
But maybe there is a less crutch solution.